# Easy way to derivatize silsesquioxanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, organosilicon-compounds

I have a polymer end-capped with a [polysilsesquioxane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silsesquioxane) (POSS) like this one $(\ce{R} = \ce{i-Bu})$:

[image: cubic silsesquioxane]

I haven't found much info on what type or reactions these POSS groups can undergo. Are there any procedures to modify the POSS moiety and convert it into an amino, carboxyl or triethoxysilane group, for example?

Also, are those $\ce{-R}$ groups easy to replace? How stable are the $\ce{Si-i-Bu}$ bonds?